# Sitecore XP 10.3.1 Installation Wizard skipped installing most items in a package

Tags: package-designer

I just encountered a surprise where Installation Wizard on a recently installed Sitecore 10.3.1 XP CM instance skipped installing most of the items in a package.  It only installed a small subset of items.  I don't see anything special about why certain items were installed and others were not.

FWIW, the Sitecore logs do not show any errors.  I've unzipped the problematic package using 7-Zip and see the items that I'm expecting.  I've checked the Master DB's Items table for one of the missing items and its not present.

I've used Package Designer & Installation Wizard hundreds of times to transfer items from one Sitecore instance to another so this is really surprising.  I installed a few other packages on the same instance before and after the problematic one and they all seemed to work as expected.

Any ideas what would cause this?

**EDIT:**  Some answers to the questions posed by Marcel Gruber:

1. I created the package on a Sitecore XP 8.1 Update 1 CM instance using PSE 5.0.0.42513.  This uses the "static" method, not "dynamic".
2. This particular package specified "master:\content" and its subitems.  It's interesting to note that the "Content" node has 3 children.  2 of the children are common "Folder" types but only 1 was created in the destination.  (This indicates the problem doesn't have to do with a missing template.)
3. Yes, I can replicate this in multiple envs.
4. Re "deeply nested", the hierarchy under "master:\content" has a decent amount of depth but this hasn't changed since the last time I successfully did this.
5. It looks like the PSE code is specifying the following so I'm not asked at install time:
   id_InstallMode=Overwrite
   id_VersionMergeMode=Undefined

**Some new information:**

6. I found an older copy of the same package and it still fully installs in both destination envs.  From comparing the logs from the attempted installs of the "bad" and "good" packages, I can see roughly where in the item progression the "bad" package install is failing.  I'm trying to narrow it down to a specific item.

**More new information:**

7. I've been watching the Sitecore logs as the problematic zip is being processed and it always fails at the same point.  However, I haven't found anything specific to the last item processed (or the ones before and after it) that would be the cause of the failures.  None of those items have changed since the zip file that worked.
8. When retrying my tests, it doesn't matter if I delete the existing items before installation or install on top of existing items.
9. Under sitecore/Content, I have three folders.  If I create a single zip on the source env specifying "Content" and all sub-items, installation fails on the dest env.  If I create a single zip specifying the three folders and their sub-items, it fails about 6 items later in the item progression.  If I create three zips, one for each of the three folders and their sub-items, installing all 3 zips works fine.  So, it **appears** I have a workaround (but I need to verify in another env).
10. I don't understand why the Installation Wizard is silently failing (or deciding there are no more items to process) without emitting anything to the logs.  **Is there a way to enable more verbose logging?**

Comment: Please provide as much information as you can about the package. How did you generate it? Statically or dynamically? Can you replicate this issue across multiple environments? Are the items deeply nested? Did you specify merge options when creating the package or were you prompted for merge strategy when you were running the install? One guess is that you may have specified merge options for certain sources at the time of package creation which caused the items not to be installed.

Comment: Does the issue occur on a vanilla install of Sitecore?

Comment: @MarcelGruber -- Yes it does.  (Sorry for the slow reply but it took me some time to set this test up.)  Please see above for some more new info.

Comment: Can someone please re-open this question?

Comment: Have you opened up a ticket with Sitecore Support?

Comment: @MarcelGruber -- I'm discussing with the team as we do have an active support contact with Sitecore.  However, we haven't had great success with Sitecore Support.  And, they typically avoid questions on out-of-support platforms (even though we're doing this as part of an upgrade to 10.3.1).

Comment: Ok. This is headed into tech support territory. My recommendation is to post about this in the Sitecore Slack group.